# NSLayoutManager - How to get the current font being used in the event it's different than what you set it to(e.g. unsupported characters)

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

I have an issue with NSLayoutManager. I have some translations I'm displaying. I've set a font and then I'm using `drawGlyph(forRange:, at:)` to draw a custom underline(the standard underline doesn't work for my use case). Everything works fine as long as the text being laid out is characters that are in the current font family, but if the characters are, say, Chinese characters, which are not covered by my font family, AppKit picks a font that does include them, but it doesn't seem to maintain the same character height, so the underline I'm drawing is about 5 pixels too high on the Chinese characters compared to latin.

I can use `defaultLineHeight(for: NSFont)`, but the problem is I don't know what font it's using. If I for example set the font to `Helvetica`, and the systems is going to use `NOTvetica` because it includes the needed characters, how can I know that `NOTvetica` is what's been used for these characters so that I can pass it to  `defaultLineHeight(for: NSFont)`? Obviously passing in `Helvetica` doesn't do me much good because then I'm getting measurements for a font that's not actually the one being used.

I'm currently calculating the underline location as follows:

```swift
// Get rect of text being underlined
let height = defaultLineHeight(for: myFont)
var rect = boundingRect(forGlyphRange: glyphRange, in: textContainer)
rect.size = NSSize(width: rect.width, height: height)
// Adjust rect for current font
var origin = rect.origin
origin.y += (rect.height + myFont.descender + 1)
// Create path used to draw the underline
let r = NSRect(origin: origin, size: NSSize(width: rect.width, height: thickness))
let path = NSBezierPath(roundedRect: r, xRadius: 0, yRadius: 0)
path.fill()
```

Obviously calculating where to draw the line based off a different font than what's being used leads to misplaced underlines.

This question is not answered by [How to find the default font for East Asian character in MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58901512/how-to-find-the-default-font-for-east-asian-character-in-macos) as that question only provides a response about how to find the list of default fonts, it does not provide a way to determine *which* font is being used by the current range of text. A list of 60 fonts that *might* be currently being used, is about as useless to me as a single font that's *not* being used. Also that question seems to focus specifically on finding the font for only East Asian characters, I need my code to work with potentially any characters, be they Hindi, or Thai, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSTextStorage.attribute(_:at:effectiveRange:)` on the `NSLayoutManager`'s `NSTextStorage` during `NSLayoutManagerDelegate` callbacks. `NSTextStorage` returns the actual font that is being used post fallback rather than the original font which might not support the glyphs.

For example, this gets the specific font being used to render the text which could then be used for tweaking the line fragments:

```swift
    public func layoutManager(
        _ layoutManager: NSLayoutManager,
        shouldSetLineFragmentRect lineFragmentRect: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGRect>,
        lineFragmentUsedRect: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGRect>,
        baselineOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGFloat>,
        in _: NSTextContainer,
        forGlyphRange glyphRange: NSRange
    ) -> Bool {
        let charRange = characterRange(forGlyphRange: glyphRange, actualGlyphRange: nil)
        guard let textStorage = layoutManager.textStorage else { return false }
        let actualFont = textStorage.attribute(.font, at: charRange.location, effectiveRange: nil)
        
        ... do something with the font ...
    }
```

I recommend passing nil as the effectiveRange because the font could change within the line.